# jQuery append element after every nth child which has the style display:block

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Another jQuery thing for you that I'm scratching my head over.
I have some floated divs (shown below) that are turned on and off using jQuery.
I need to append some bits after every third child element that **does not** have a style of display:none.

```
<div class="ItemList">
    <div class="Item">A</div>
    <div class="Item" style="display:none;">B</div>
    <div class="Item">C</div>
    <div class="Item">D</div>
    <div class="Item" style="display:none;">E</div>
    <div class="Item">F</div>
    <div class="Item">G</div>
    <div class="Item">H</div>
    <div class="Item">I</div>
    <div class="Item" style="display:none;">J</div>
    <div class="Item">K</div>
    <div class="Item">L</div>
    <div class="Item">M</div>
    <div class="Item">N</div>
</div>
```

I have come up with this but it isn't right!

```
$(".Item[style*='display: block']:nth-child(3n)").after("<div class='Clear'></div>");
```

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need the elements filtered before you select the `.Item` elements or after.

After elements are selected.

```
$(".Item:nth-child(3n)").filter(function(){
     return $(this).css("display") != "none";
}).after("<div class='Clear'></div>");
```

@undefined has a really good answer too.

Comment: Both this and @undefined work to some degree, but I am getting some really weird results, first few groups of three work fine but then it goes a bit mad and chucks in the appended html almost randomly (which I'm sure it is not). Just going to have a play about and see what isn't right....

Comment: Create a jsFiddle and we can work through what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:visible` selector:

```
$(".Item:visible:nth-child(3n)").after("<div class='Clear'></div>");
```

or:

```
$(".Item:nth-child(3n):visible").after("<div class='Clear'></div>");
```

Please note that the order of selectors is important.

Comment: I'm guessing I need to select the children that are visible and then check if it is the 3nth child rather than the other way round?

Both these answers and @JoeFletch's are good but I'm getting weird results. Having a tinker with it to see if I can work it at the moment!